# Best way to read object from another class without code coupling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for example we have class `Foo`

```
class Foo {

  public class Physics {
    float gravity = 9.8f;
    float seperateDistance = 10f;
  }

  public Physics physics;

  void Start(){
    physics = new Physics();
    Bar baz = AddComponent<Bar>(); 
  }

}
```

Meanwhile, in `Bar` component, we are trying to get the `gravity` value inside `Foo`'s physics.

Currently this is the only way I can think of. which i somehow feel not good about. If class `Foo` is removed then `Bar` will not working anymore, which i guess is not a good practice.

Inside the `baz` we created in Foo:

```
void Start(){
       //...
  float gravity = getComponent<Foo>().physics.gravity;
      //...
}
```

Is there any better ways to do this?

Comment: _"i feel like directly access is wrong"_ -- without knowing, it wouldn't even be possible to know what answer you want. And even if you could explain yourself, your question would be primarily opinion based, and likely still too broad (due to the large number of possible alternatives). Your question might be more on-topic at codereview.stackexchange.com or softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but if you want to post at either of those sites, take care to read their introductory help, to make sure you fix your question to be well-presented and on-topic on those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, the issue that you're worried about is class coupling. As Georg's answer said, you should be using properties, not fields. But you can avoid class coupling by injecting an interface into Bar that Foo implements. This means that you don't need a Foo to code Bar:

```
public interface IGravitySource
{
    double Gravity { get; }
}

public sealed class Foo : IGravitySource
{
    private readonly Physics myPrivatePhysics = new Physics();

    private sealed class Physics
    {
        public double Gravity { get; } = 9.81;

        public double Smoothness { get; } = 0.05;
    }

    public double Gravity => myPrivatePhysics.Gravity;
}

public sealed class Bar
{
    private readonly IGravitySource gravitySource;

    public Bar(IGravitySource gravitySource)
    {
        this.gravitySource = gravitySource;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //...
        var gravity = gravitySource.Gravity;
        gravity += 1;
        //...
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Technically, you might be introducing debt by effectively re-implementing the properties of IGravitySource in multiple places. One solution to this is to have the IGravitySource only have a single member, IGravity. This way, if you decide to extend IGravity with direction, you don't need to change the implementation of Foo:

```
public interface IGravitySource
{
    IGravity Gravity { get; }
}

internal interface IGravity
{
    double AccelerationDueToGravity { get; }
}

public sealed class Foo : IGravitySource
{
    private readonly Physics myPrivatePhysics = new Physics();

    private sealed class Physics : IGravity
    {
        public double AccelerationDueToGravity { get; } = 9.81;

        public double Smoothness { get; } = 0.05;
    }

    public IGravity Gravity => myPrivatePhysics;
}

public sealed class Bar
{
    private readonly IGravitySource gravitySource;

    public Bar(IGravitySource gravitySource)
    {
        this.gravitySource = gravitySource;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //...
        var gravity = gravitySource.Gravity.AccelerationDueToGravity;
        gravity += 1;
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done through properties which are basically pairs of two methods, a getter and setter method.

To use them, just exchange `public Physics physics;` by `public Physics physics { get; set; }`. There is no need to change the consuming code since properties are accessed like fields in C#. However, properties also allow you to customize the getter and setter. The good thing is that such a modification is transparent to client code, so you can change the access to that property without having to change code that consumes the property. Further, properties can be virtual or abstract and are allowed to be part of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there's a Foo component attached

```
void Start() {
    //Check if there's Foo, if no then give them default to 3;
    float gravity = GetComponent<Foo>() ? GetComponent<Foo>().physics.gravity : 3;
    //...
}
```

Or you can also add RequireComponentAttribute to the class Bar, so that Foo will always tied to Bar [RequireComponentAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)

But if you mean 'what if Foo Class(not component) doesn't exist anymore.
I suggest you to do Method Injection like Adam Brown answers.

But there's another solution when class is no longer exist.
here's my thought.

Create a special Attribute to detemine which field is shareable. and then get the field wh use that Attribute.

Example : 
of course this isn't tested yet, but by theory it will work.

```
//Some special attribute 
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class ShareFieldAttribute : Attribute {

}

class Foo {

    public class Physics {
        float gravity = 9.8f;
        float seperateDistance = 10f;
    }

    //mark ShareField attribute to this field
    [ShareField]
    public Physics physics;

    void Start(){

        physics = new Physics();
        Bar baz = AddComponent<Bar>(); 
    }

}

class Bar {
    void Start() {
        //Get the field 'public Physics physics' by name and Type
        Physics physics = GetShareField<Physics>("physics", null);
        float gravity = physics ? physics.gravity : 3;
        //...
    }

    //Method Helper
    public T GetShareField<T>(string fieldName, T defaultValue)
    {
        foreach(var c in GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>())
        {
            var fields = c.GetType().GetFields().Where(field => field.FieldType == T && field.Name == fieldName && field.IsDefined(typeof(ShareFieldAttribute), false));
            return (T)fields[0].GetValue(c);
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```